# Check return value without increasing Cognitive Complexity (SonarLint)

Tags: c, sonarlint, cognitive-complexity

I have a piece of code which is marked with a high score of cognitive complexity by SonarLint. In this piece of code functions are called and afterwards the return value is checked. So it has the following structure:

```
ret = func(arg_a1, arg_a2);
if(ret!=0){return ret;}
some other statements
ret = func(arg_b1, arg_b2);
if(ret!=0){return ret;}
some other statements
ret = func(arg_c1, arg_c2);
if(ret!=0){return ret;}
some other statements
ret = func(arg_d1, arg_d2);
if(ret!=0){return ret;}
some other statements
...
return 0;
```

In the logic of SonarLint each if clause increases the cognitive complexity by one. The cognitive complexity does not increase with calling a lot of functions, but it increases with calling a lot of functions and checking return values.

Should I just ignore coginitve complexity in this case?

Comment: The question is probably too opinion-based for SO. I prefer these "early returns" over nested if-statements but I know others that strongly argues that functions should have only one return statement. In other words.... I would "just ignore coginitve complexity in this case" but you may get other opinions.

Comment: It is not just SonarLint that considers this code complex. When reading the code, it is very difficult to see how far the execution will proceed before returning. If the functions have side effects, the final state is more or less unknown. When calling a set of functions without conditions, we know that they are all called.

Comment: Early return is well understood by experienced programmers. It makes more sense than tracing through 'n' more conditionals `if( ret == 0 ) /* do more */` hoping to bounce out the bottom of a function...